# How to set active sheet in Google Sheets with PHP?

Tags: php, google-sheets

How to set, for example, 2nd sheet as active?
Right now I set a document I want to edit, but I don't know how to select specific sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by including the Sheet name with the range you want to read/edit.

Example: `SheetName!A1:B2;`

**Reference:**

[PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php)

[Read and Writing Cell Values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values)